# What is the exact usage of exists()?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using it as
`if ModelName.objects.get(fieldname=value).exists():`

I either get the error 'ModelName' object has no attribute 'exists' or it throws a `DoesNotExist` exception.

Related doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply it to queryset, not a single object, try:

```
if ModelName.objects.filter(fieldname=value).exists():
```

If queryset is not empty, this will return `True`.